# How to add text animation to wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, text

I'm stuck with this code.. I'm tryng to add [this](https://codepen.io/hendrysadrak/pen/VLMOMJ) text animation to a text in a wordpress page only... any ideas?
thanks to everyone.

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="txt anim-text-flow">How are you? Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your css and html and any JavaScript being used?

Comment: look the css is not natural css it's SCSS so it may not work for every platform

Comment: andrew if you click on "this" i will go to codepen link console and you will see all the code

Answer (score 1):

I just extracted plain css and js from codepen and add here. It's working. Make sure you enqueued these css and js properly in wordpress. Although I have noticed you are using "visual composer" , visual composer plugin has option to add custom css and js, you can utilize that too.

```js
    $('.txt').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = $.trim(html).split("");

  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});
```

```css
     /*
 * Animation module with all animation code
 */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300);
.anim-text-flow,
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover {
  /*
   * Animation variables
   */
  /*
   * Elements settings
   */
  /*
   * Keyframe loop
   */
  /*
   * Element animation delay loop
   */
}
.anim-text-flow span,
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span {
  -webkit-animation-name: anim-text-flow-keys;
          animation-name: anim-text-flow-keys;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
          animation-duration: 50s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #5cd687;
  }
  5% {
    color: #d6895c;
  }
  10% {
    color: #d6875c;
  }
  15% {
    color: #d6a15c;
  }
  20% {
    color: #c2d65c;
  }
  25% {
    color: #5cd6a3;
  }
  30% {
    color: #d6625c;
  }
  35% {
    color: #d2d65c;
  }
  40% {
    color: #c2d65c;
  }
  45% {
    color: #d69f5c;
  }
  50% {
    color: #d66e5c;
  }
  55% {
    color: #d6a15c;
  }
  60% {
    color: #d65ca7;
  }
  65% {
    color: #d65c64;
  }
  70% {
    color: #5cd69f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #89d65c;
  }
  80% {
    color: #9f5cd6;
  }
  85% {
    color: #7a5cd6;
  }
  90% {
    color: #5cd672;
  }
  95% {
    color: #785cd6;
  }
  100% {
    color: #665cd6;
  }
}
@keyframes anim-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #5cd687;
  }
  5% {
    color: #d6895c;
  }
  10% {
    color: #d6875c;
  }
  15% {
    color: #d6a15c;
  }
  20% {
    color: #c2d65c;
  }
  25% {
    color: #5cd6a3;
  }
  30% {
    color: #d6625c;
  }
  35% {
    color: #d2d65c;
  }
  40% {
    color: #c2d65c;
  }
  45% {
    color: #d69f5c;
  }
  50% {
    color: #d66e5c;
  }
  55% {
    color: #d6a15c;
  }
  60% {
    color: #d65ca7;
  }
  65% {
    color: #d65c64;
  }
  70% {
    color: #5cd69f;
  }
  75% {
    color: #89d65c;
  }
  80% {
    color: #9f5cd6;
  }
  85% {
    color: #7a5cd6;
  }
  90% {
    color: #5cd672;
  }
  95% {
    color: #785cd6;
  }
  100% {
    color: #665cd6;
  }
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(1),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.8s;
          animation-delay: -19.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(2),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.6s;
          animation-delay: -19.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(3),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.4s;
          animation-delay: -19.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(4),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.2s;
          animation-delay: -19.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(5),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19s;
          animation-delay: -19s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(6),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.8s;
          animation-delay: -18.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(7),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.6s;
          animation-delay: -18.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(8),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.4s;
          animation-delay: -18.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(9),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.2s;
          animation-delay: -18.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(10),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18s;
          animation-delay: -18s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(11),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.8s;
          animation-delay: -17.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(12),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.6s;
          animation-delay: -17.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(13),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(13) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.4s;
          animation-delay: -17.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(14),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(14) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.2s;
          animation-delay: -17.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(15),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(15) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17s;
          animation-delay: -17s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(16),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(16) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.8s;
          animation-delay: -16.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(17),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(17) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.6s;
          animation-delay: -16.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(18),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(18) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.4s;
          animation-delay: -16.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(19),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(19) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.2s;
          animation-delay: -16.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(20),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(20) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16s;
          animation-delay: -16s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(21),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(21) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.8s;
          animation-delay: -15.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(22),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(22) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.6s;
          animation-delay: -15.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(23),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(23) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.4s;
          animation-delay: -15.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(24),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(24) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.2s;
          animation-delay: -15.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(25),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(25) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15s;
          animation-delay: -15s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(26),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(26) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.8s;
          animation-delay: -14.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(27),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(27) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.6s;
          animation-delay: -14.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(28),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(28) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.4s;
          animation-delay: -14.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(29),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(29) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.2s;
          animation-delay: -14.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(30),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(30) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14s;
          animation-delay: -14s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(31),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(31) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.8s;
          animation-delay: -13.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(32),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(32) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.6s;
          animation-delay: -13.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(33),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(33) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.4s;
          animation-delay: -13.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(34),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(34) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.2s;
          animation-delay: -13.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(35),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(35) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13s;
          animation-delay: -13s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(36),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(36) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.8s;
          animation-delay: -12.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(37),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(37) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.6s;
          animation-delay: -12.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(38),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(38) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.4s;
          animation-delay: -12.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(39),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(39) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.2s;
          animation-delay: -12.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(40),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(40) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12s;
          animation-delay: -12s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(41),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(41) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.8s;
          animation-delay: -11.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(42),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(42) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.6s;
          animation-delay: -11.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(43),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(43) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.4s;
          animation-delay: -11.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(44),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(44) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.2s;
          animation-delay: -11.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(45),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(45) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11s;
          animation-delay: -11s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(46),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(46) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.8s;
          animation-delay: -10.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(47),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(47) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.6s;
          animation-delay: -10.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(48),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(48) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.4s;
          animation-delay: -10.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(49),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(49) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.2s;
          animation-delay: -10.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(50),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(50) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10s;
          animation-delay: -10s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(51),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(51) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.8s;
          animation-delay: -9.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(52),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(52) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.6s;
          animation-delay: -9.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(53),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(53) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.4s;
          animation-delay: -9.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(54),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(54) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.2s;
          animation-delay: -9.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(55),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(55) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9s;
          animation-delay: -9s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(56),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(56) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.8s;
          animation-delay: -8.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(57),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(57) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.6s;
          animation-delay: -8.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(58),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(58) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.4s;
          animation-delay: -8.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(59),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(59) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.2s;
          animation-delay: -8.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(60),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(60) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8s;
          animation-delay: -8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(61),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(61) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.8s;
          animation-delay: -7.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(62),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(62) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.6s;
          animation-delay: -7.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(63),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(63) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.4s;
          animation-delay: -7.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(64),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(64) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.2s;
          animation-delay: -7.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(65),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(65) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7s;
          animation-delay: -7s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(66),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(66) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.8s;
          animation-delay: -6.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(67),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(67) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.6s;
          animation-delay: -6.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(68),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(68) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.4s;
          animation-delay: -6.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(69),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(69) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.2s;
          animation-delay: -6.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(70),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(70) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6s;
          animation-delay: -6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(71),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(71) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.8s;
          animation-delay: -5.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(72),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(72) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.6s;
          animation-delay: -5.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(73),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(73) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.4s;
          animation-delay: -5.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(74),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(74) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.2s;
          animation-delay: -5.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(75),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(75) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5s;
          animation-delay: -5s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(76),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(76) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.8s;
          animation-delay: -4.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(77),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(77) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.6s;
          animation-delay: -4.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(78),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(78) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.4s;
          animation-delay: -4.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(79),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(79) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.2s;
          animation-delay: -4.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(80),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(80) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
          animation-delay: -4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(81),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(81) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.8s;
          animation-delay: -3.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(82),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(82) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.6s;
          animation-delay: -3.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(83),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(83) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.4s;
          animation-delay: -3.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(84),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(84) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.2s;
          animation-delay: -3.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(85),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(85) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
          animation-delay: -3s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(86),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(86) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.8s;
          animation-delay: -2.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(87),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(87) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.6s;
          animation-delay: -2.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(88),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(88) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.4s;
          animation-delay: -2.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(89),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(89) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.2s;
          animation-delay: -2.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(90),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(90) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
          animation-delay: -2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(91),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(91) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.8s;
          animation-delay: -1.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(92),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(92) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.6s;
          animation-delay: -1.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(93),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(93) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.4s;
          animation-delay: -1.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(94),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(94) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.2s;
          animation-delay: -1.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(95),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(95) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
          animation-delay: -1s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(96),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(96) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
          animation-delay: -0.8s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(97),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(97) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
          animation-delay: -0.6s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(98),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(98) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
          animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(99),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(99) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
          animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.anim-text-flow span:nth-of-type(100),
.anim-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(100) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}

body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fefefe;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.txt {
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="txt anim-text-flow">How are you? Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tamin!!! it worked!!! i missed <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> before div class!!! thanks again

Comment: hi Tamim, i just realized that with your code with <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> this, i have a conflict with an installed plugin in wordpress... how i can solve the conflict? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this element on your wordpress post content as html

```html
<span class="yourclassname anim-text-flow">How are you? Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.yourclassname').html(function(i, html) {
      var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
      return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
    });
<script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i know that, but this is not my question...
i would like to know how i can add this code in a wordpress page.. for a text that i have there...

Comment: Oh I see, I will change the answer

Comment: then i have to add html/css/js file in the wp content root? sorry i'm a bit newbie for this kind of things..

Comment: by adding your code up there.. site go in 500 internal server error, should be something wrong? changed "yourclassname" with txt and .yourclassname in js with .txt that is css class in the codepen code right?

Comment: You can use Insert Header and Footer plugin to do this.. Yeah that's right the js should point to the element, it can be the id or class name..